# CSV remove everything after the 4th comma

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV file with way to much (unnecessary) information.
There are only 4 strings of information that is useful for me and what I'd like to store in a database.

Luckily, they're the first 4 'columns' of the CSV file. But I can't extract them easily. Is there a way or a formula that helps me do this?

The CSV looks something like this:

```
number, data-string, data-string, url, unimportant-data, unimportant-data
```

How can I get the first 4 columns from this?

Comment: What is your problem?  Why not just delete those columns in Excel?

Comment: The problem is that it's a csv file, so only rows with the 'columns' separated by comma's.

Comment: If you open a CSV file in Excel, it will split it into columns by the commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Text to Column" from "Data" to split the data. Then you can remove unwanted columns.

Step 1: Select the rows you want to convert

Step 2: Navigate to **Data** `-->` **Text to column**

Step 3: From the window **select "Delemited"** in the radio box and click next

Step 4: Select **checkbox "Comma"** only, deselect other and click next

step 5: Select destination to a new cell and click finish.

[image: shown the last step here]